# iPhone and PhoneGap remove cache.db file

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I'm building an application for iPhone(iOS 5) using Phonegap(Html + Javascript + Css), and i noticed that all the requests and responses the application makes to our server are being saved in a cache.db file on the phone.

This means that any passwords the user entered in our login screen will also be saved in this file, which is not secure.

Is there any way to stop this file from recording all of the app's communication with the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this, the guys at PhoneGap helped me figure it out:

It seems I wasn't using SSL and once I started using it didn't save any communication with the server in the cache.db file.